# Query with import range for multiple google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from different GOOGLE sheets with the below formula, suggesting the correct formula getting Error "AS Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col18. Please guide for correct formula" & "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

```
=Query({IMPORTRANGE("1srpJok8Clb_hIW0mVfx74VjrAOmGmHXavXFZ1H77pnQ","Daily DPS Delhi!A4330:R");IMPORTRANGE("1__6apvi3ICKaMQz7R4SNzm_KXtCIERavBTxQ8Dkf1bs","Trip Data!A174295:R");IMPORTRANGE("1r3CbiyP_AFcpvm4eNvJO_VvNWZjxkrIHdiOgGhyLZQg","DPS Bangalore!A20640:R")},"Select Col1,Col18,Col7,Col11,Col12 where Col1 is not null")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({
IMPORTRANGE("1srpJok8Clb_hIW0mVfx74VjrAOmGmHXavXFZ1H77pnQ","Daily DPS Delhi!A4330:R");
IMPORTRANGE("1__6apvi3ICKaMQz7R4SNzm_KXtCIERavBTxQ8Dkf1bs","Trip Data!A174295:R");
IMPORTRANGE("1r3CbiyP_AFcpvm4eNvJO_VvNWZjxkrIHdiOgGhyLZQg","DPS Bangalore!A20640:R")},
 "select Col1,Col18,Col7,Col11,Col12 
  where Col1 is not null")
```

the formula is ok but you need to run each importrange separately and allow access to connect all spreadsheets. only then you can use this formula

Comment: Getting error as "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

Comment: @Akash it only means one of your importranges is not working rg. is not connected. did you run each importrange separately?